# Quartz .NET Scheduler v2.4.1 stops after 10 repeats

Tags: c#, console, scheduler, schedule

I have a simple Console Application which is using Quartz .NET Scheduler v2.4.1
and it's simply writing actual time.

When I build my app it's only working 10 times and then stops.

[image]

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MySchedule.GetValue();
    }
}

public static class MySchedule
{
    public static void GetValue()
    {
        var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

        scheduler.Start();

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>().Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(builder =>

        builder.WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
        .OnEveryDay()
        .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourMinuteAndSecondOfDay(9, 40, 0))).Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}

  public class MyJob : IJob
    {
        public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now.ToString(new CultureInfo("en"))}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I took a look at config file to change *threadCount* but it didn't work for me.

Any help would be greatful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program does not wait at all. Your `Main` method just ends. Make it wait if your want the program to run longer. For example with a `Console.ReadLine`. You can then remove the user interaction from your job. You may also want to have a handle on the scheduler while the program is running, I don't know what happens if the garbage collector figures out you have dropped the last reference to it.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var scheduler = MySchedule.GetValue();

        Console.WriteLine("Scheduler started. Press [Enter] to quit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public static class MySchedule
{
    public static IScheduler GetValue()
    {
        var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

        scheduler.Start();

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<MyJob>().Build();

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(builder =>

        builder.WithIntervalInSeconds(1)
        .OnEveryDay()
        .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourMinuteAndSecondOfDay(9, 40, 0))).Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);

        return scheduler;
    }
}

public class MyJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString(new CultureInfo("en")));
    }
}
```